# after call does not save data flutter

Tags: flutter

I make a call where I checked it happens correctly, but then when I try to retrieve a data received by the call me from null. I can not understand why but .. quancuno of you can give me a hand?

```
    Future<UserDataByCode> sendCode() async {
  var url = "$_baseUrl/api/users/ABC124";

  try {
    var response = await _dio.get(
      url,
      options: Options(headers: {"x-access-token": _loginData.token}),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userData = UserDataByCode.fromJson(response.data);
      return userDataByCode;
    } else {
      _printLog("Upload sendCode 2", response, level: Level.WARNING);
      return null;
    }
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    _printLog("Upload sendCode 3", e, level: Level.SHOUT);
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the UserDataByCode model which should return the data to insert as name in the text after making the call, but it returns null:import 'dart:convert';

```
class UserDataByCode {
  String firstName;
  String surname;
  int balance;
  double ticketValue;
  int remainingTickets;

  UserDataByCode(
      {this.firstName,
      this.surname,
      this.balance,
      this.ticketValue,
      this.remainingTickets,
      });

  UserDataByCode.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    firstName = json['user_name_first'];
    surname = json['user_name_surname'];
    balance = json['tckt_balance'];
    ticketValue = json['ticket_value'];
    remainingTickets = json['remaining_tickets'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['firstName'] = this.firstName;
    data['surname'] = this.surname;
    data['balance'] = this.balance;
    data['ticketValue'] = this.ticketValue;
    data['remainingTickets'] = this.remainingTickets;
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return jsonEncode(toJson());
  }
}
```

In my ContentManager I put this, since for the other calls whoever worked before me did well I hurt the same thing ..

```
      Future<UserDataByCode> getUserDataByCode() async {
    return _userDataByCode = await connection.sendCode();
  }

  UserDataByCode getUserDataByCodeSync() {
    if (_userDataByCode == null) {
      print("Still no _userDataByCode");
      return null;
    }
    return _userDataByCode;
  }
```

UPDATE:

[Receive this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaUin.png)

UPDATE 2:

```
    return FutureBuilder<UserData>(
    future: contentManager.getUserData(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
```

All widget code:

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _buttonHeight = size.height * .05;
    //double splitPoint = size.height / 7;

    return FutureBuilder<UserData>(
        future: contentManager.getUserData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
          if (snapUserData.hasError)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("There was some error"),
              ),
            );
          if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appColors.yellow)),
              ),
            );
            return Container(
              color: appColors.primaryColor,
              child: ListView(
                primary: false,
                      children: [
                        // TITOLO
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                                    localization.showQR,
                                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                                      color: appColors.green,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Container(
                                    child: qrCodeHolder
                                ),
                            ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Container(
                                  child: AutoSizeText(
                                    localization.home_subLabel,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                                      color: appColors.green,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          //top: size.height * .02,
                          //right: size.width * .02,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: TextField(
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                                    ],
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      filled: true,
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Image.asset("assets/images/send.png"),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  connection.sendCode().then((value) {
                                      if (value != null) {
                                        showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => PaymentDialog());
                                      } else {
                                        showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => PaymentDialog());
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }
                                //onPressed: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => PaymentDialog()),
                              ),
                            ]
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
              );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the information of the object you expect to receive?

Comment: @FelipeVergara i get this from the call, however after i do it and try to call UserDataByCode.firstName from null

i add a photo

Comment: @FelipeVergara why do i get nill?

Comment: @FelipeVergara I really can't understand why

Comment: In addition to modifying the information you return in the sendCode function, in what part of the code do you invoke the getUserDataByCode function?

Comment: @FelipeVergara here, I realized now not to recall it at all .. only now in the view where I make the call and show the pop-up with the data I need, I already recall this however .. how can I recall what I need getUserDataByCode ? 

I upload code 2

Comment: In UPDATED 2, you are calling a function that I do not know, you should call the getUserDataByCode function and also change the data type of the FutureBuilder <UserDataByCode>

Comment: @FelipeVergara contain user information, which I need, how can I add this too?

Comment: @FelipeVergara I try to insert contentManager.getUserDataByCode() in void initState() but receive always null

Comment: Can you add all the Widget code?

Comment: @FelipeVergara yes sure, i update.. thank for your help

Comment: Where does the variable "content Manager" come from? It will not be possible to see if it comes from another widget or is declared at the beginning of the widget.

Comment: @FelipeVergara I make "I'import" of file "content Manager.dart"

Comment: @FelipeVergara gives me null when I call
showDialog (context: context, builder: (_) => PaymentDialog ());
where I expect to see the data

Comment: Perfect, now just to be clear, you need the information that returns from this sendCode function, right?

Comment: @FelipeVergara yes right

Comment: it's always there for me "nill" @FelipeVergara

Comment: Perfect I am creating an example for you, can you upload the code of the ContentManager file?

Comment: @FelipeVergara
Sure Thanks 
https://easyupload.io/xzasny

Comment: @FelipeVergara how come i don't get anything?

Comment: From what I can see, you are invoking the functions wrong, try testing with this code:

1: First, modify the return of the sendCode function, it should look like this:

return UserDataByCode.fromJson(response.data);

2: Then comment all the code in your main widget and paste this, this code calls the getUserDataByCode function of your ContentManager class. Then if there is no error, the data will be printed by console.

Comment: return FutureBuilder<UserDataByCode>(
        future: contentManager.getUserDataByCode(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserDataByCode> snapUserDataByCode) {
          if (snapUserDataByCode.hasError)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("There was some error"),
              ),
            );

          print('WORK: ${snapUserDataByCode.data}');
          return Container();
        });

Comment: @FelipeVergara work.. print right but why affter receive nil ?

Comment: @FelipeVergara print this:
flutter: WORK: null
flutter: WORK: null
flutter: WORK: {"firstName":"Giulio","surname":"Mandragora","balance":20646,"userID":578,"ticketValue":0.01,"remainingTickets":8}

Comment: That is solved by replacing your if conditional, by this validation.

return FutureBuilder<UserDataByCode>(
        future: contentManager.getUserDataByCode(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserDataByCode> snapUserDataByCode) {
          if (!snapUserDataByCode.hasData)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("There was some error"),
              ),
            );
          print('WORK: ${snapUserDataByCode.data}');
          return Container();
        });

Comment: Print null the first two times because there is no validation that verifies if the Snapshot has data, there is only a validation in case of error, but since no error occurs it prints null, now I send you an example that verifies if it has data.

You can also try the following that if it does not have data it prints a loading.

Comment: return FutureBuilder<UserDataByCode>(
        future: contentManager.getUserDataByCode(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserDataByCode> snapUserDataByCode) {
          if (!snapUserDataByCode.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          print('WORK: ${snapUserDataByCode.data}');
          return Container();
        });

Comment: @FelipeVergara i changed as you said, print what i need right away .. but i always get error nill

Comment: @FelipeVergara when it fetches the variable to be inserted as text .. why?

Comment: @FelipeVergara I can't understand and solve ..

Comment: So, I am confused, in the widget it manages to bring the information? Where is the error occurring now specifically?

Comment: @FelipeVergara when i call PaymentDialog i go to alert and I try to recall the data I need from the call we saw earlier with "userDataByCode.firstName" in a Text

Comment: In order to access the FutureBuilder data you must access the following way:
`snapUserData.data.firstName`, Try printing this inside the onTap.

Comment: where is it? she doesn't let me put it in, she tells me it's missing "snapUserData", I have to create a variable ? @FelipeVergara

Comment: sorry, try this: `snapUserDataByCode.data.firstName`

Comment: @FelipeVergara work, print what i need

Comment: flutter: WORK: Giulio

Comment: but why on the next screen if you lose it?

Comment: You lose the information because it is in another context, what you can do is pass the information through the parameters when you invoke the widget (PaymentDialog (data: snapUserDataByCode.data)) but there you would have to modify that widget and declare the type of data that you will receive, etc.

But that's another matter, you could also use a state manager like: bloc, provider, get, riverpod, etc to optimize management.

Comment: @FelipeVergara and how can i solve i don't understand?

Comment: Of course I can help you, but we could close this thread, and create a new one with your new question, because this is already too long.

Comment: @FelipeVergara eh by now we are finished though, it is enough just that I pass the data and recall it. However PaymentDialog (data: snapUserDataByCode.data) I add this as a parameter and then in the widget how do I call it?

Comment: PaymentDialog, is it a stateless or stateful widget?

Comment: @FelipeVergara thank you so much, is this 
https://easyupload.io/293rv0

Comment: Put this inside of `class PaymentDialog extends StatefulWidget {`

`final UserDataByCode data;
  PaymentDiaolg({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);` 

`@override ... }`

Comment: Then in your initState assign to the variable that you already have declared (userDataByCode) the value that you receive by parameters like this: `userDataByCode = this.widget.data`;

Comment: oh great! fantastic work :) thanks you so much

Comment: @FelipeVergara since by now you have seen the code and the call, can I ask you one last thing?

Comment: Sure! tell me your question :)

Comment: @FelipeVergara in the final call it is "ABC124", but it must be set by the user. I have a textfield before the call I make, in which I should take the code that is written there and put it in the call "onPressed: () async {
                                   connection.sendCode (). then ((value) {"

Comment: so that it is added to the call I make as a prefix "_baseUrl/api/users$code"

Comment: any idea how can implement a "code" that is input of textfiled to add to path of sendCode() function ? @FelipeVergara

Comment: What you should do is declare a variable in your widget and store the value obtained from the TextField there,
then when you click on the IconButton, the function `connection.sendCode (variable) .then (...)` is executed, also
you must modify your sendCode function and it should be as follows:
Future <UserDataByCode> sendCode (string variable) {var url = "$ _baseUrl / api / users / $ variable"; }

Comment: It is probable that you have problems, because you will modify the function that you invoke in futureBuilder, and it will ask you for a parameter that you do not yet know, in those cases you should set one by default or know the value that will go in the parameter from before.

Comment: @FelipeVergara i put this but retur null

Comment: connection.sendCode(code).then((value) {
        future: contentManager.getUserDataByCode(code),

  Future<UserDataByCode> getUserDataByCode(String code) async {
    return _userDataByCode = await connection.sendCode(code);
  }